# Is it possible to send functions through the Firefox SDK's port.emit()?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

When I trying to send a function through port.emit it ends up null on the other side. If I change it to a simple string it works fine. Can you not send functions through emit?

```
self.port.emit("requestBackground", someFunction);
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is a great resource, but every question you've asked points to the fact that you haven't read the clear and exhaustive documentation that the SDK team has created. Have a look at the [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides) for a good overview of SDK concepts.

Comment: As [willma](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1720014/willlma) said, Stackoverflow is a great resource. However, you should put some effort effort into solving your questions prior to asking here. The information in the answer I posted was completely found by clicking on the first result of a Google search for [port.emit](https://www.google.com/search?q=port.emit&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). You can find Mozilla documentation by looking on the [Mozilla Developer Network](http://developer.mozilla.org/) (MDN) or [searching MDN](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=port.emit+site%3Adeveloper.mozilla.org)

Comment: yoyo this is prefectly fine, ignore willma, ask whnever you need. The documentation like they both say is exhaustive which infers overwhelming. @Mayken you were awesome for posting solution below for helping him with that. There is nothing wrong in helping people find stuff in docs, I actually have trouble with that lots of times too. Especially on on X11 and CoreFoundation stuff. When I encounter negative comments it really hinders my development/morale. So they may have read it so that's not the fact, the fact is they weren't able to find/identify it and we should not mind helping with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the documentation for [`port.emit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port#port.emit%28%29) indicates:

> It may be called with any number of parameters, but is most likely to
>   be called with a name for the message and an optional payload. The
>   payload can be any value that is [serializable to JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port#JSON-Serializable_Values).

Clicking on the link about it being [serializable to JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port#JSON-Serializable_Values) would have told you:

> However, you do have to ensure that the payload can be serialized to
>   JSON. This means that it needs to be a string, number, boolean, null,
>   array of JSON-serializable values, or an object whose property values
>   are themselves JSON-serializable. **This means you can't send
>   functions**, and if the object contains methods they won't be encoded.