# How emit function in firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Can i emit function from one file to another in firefox extension? Example:

**main.js**

```
data = function() {
   return fn();
}

panel.port.emit("resp", data);
```

**panel.js**

```
self.port.on('resp', function(fn) {
   return fn("some");
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot "emit" them through *channels*, but you could export and import them statically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox SDK port sending functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27552270/firefox-sdk-port-sending-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [port API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/port#JSON-serializable_values) only supports JSON-serializeable data.